# Cannot import WebWorker file in Vue 3 app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-worker, comlink

I would like to use Comlink in my Vue 3 application and I think Comlink just works fine however when I try to reference my worker for new Worker() I think it fails to take hold onto that file.
My tree looks like this:
src
--pages
----page.vue
--workers
----worker.js

My worker.js:

```js
import * as Comlink from 'comlink';

const worker = {
  trial() {
    return 'hello';
  },
};

Comlink.expose(worker);
```

My page.vue:

```js
import * as Comlink from "comlink";

export default {
  methods: {
    tryOnClick() {
      const worker = new Worker("../../workers/worker.js");
      Comlink.wrap(worker);
      worker.trial();
    },
  },
};
```

(Later I would use my worker in a manager class and not directly in the page I just want to try it out)
This gives me the error in the console:

```
worker.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

When I open this error up it seems like it fails at the very beginning of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

How should I reference my worker.js when I initialize the new Worker?

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of your directory tree?

Comment: Of course here you go (the names are changed in the post for easier understanding):
https://i.ibb.co/0X50PmN/Screenshot-2021-10-20-090634.png